# Unable to write text on mouseclick area on Image

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv

I am trying to draw text on Image where the user clicks.
Getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/ashish/td.py", line 35, in draw_text
    cv2.putText(img, "OpenCV + Jurassic Park!!!", (event.x,event.y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    #adding the image
    File = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="F:/",title='Choose an image.')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(File))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")

    #function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def draw_text(event):
        cv2.putText(img, "OpenCV + Jurassic Park!!!", (event.x,event.y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Text", img)
    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>",draw_text)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your `img` is `ImageTK` object from `tkinter` but `cv2` is not part of `tkitner` and `cv2.putText` doesn't work with `ImageTK`. It needs something different. `cv2` has own function to read image and it creates object which you can use with `putText()` . But `canvas` has function to display text on top of image and you don't need `cv2`. But it can't be saved in file as image with text. But `Image` also has function to draw text on image and it can be saved in file. So finally you don't need `cv2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` is `ImageTK` object from `tkinter` but `cv2` is not part of `tkinter` and `cv2.putText` doesn't work with `ImageTK`. It needs something different. `cv2` has own function to read image and it creates object which you can use with `cv2.putText()`.

But `canvas` has function to display text on top of image and you don't need `cv2`. But it can't be saved in file as image with text.

But `Image` has function to draw text on image and it can be saved in file.

So finally you don't need `cv2`.

---

I use `Image.Draw` to create object on which I can put text or draw line/square/etc.
After adding text I replace image on canvas.

This method create image with text which you can save in file (`img.save()`)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw

# function to be called when mouse is clicked
def draw_text(event):
    global imgtk
    global cv_img

    # create object for drawing
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    # put text
    draw.text((event.x,event.y), "ImageDraw + Jurassic Park!!!")

    # replace old image
    canvas.delete(cv_img_id)    
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    cv_img_id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=imgtk, anchor="nw")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    #adding the image
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="F:/",title='Choose an image.')
    img = Image.open(file)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    cv_img_id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=imgtk, anchor="nw")

    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>", draw_text)

    root.mainloop()
```

---

Using `canvas.create_text` you can put text on top of image which you can move/remove later but it doesn't create image with text which you can save in file.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# function to be called when mouse is clicked
def draw_text(event):
    canvas.create_text((event.x,event.y), text="Canvas + Jurassic Park!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    #adding the image
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="F:/",title='Choose an image.')
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file))
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=imgtk, anchor="nw")

    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>", draw_text)

    root.mainloop()
```