# How to change image in tkinter by mouseclick?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive been trying a lot to get my code working. My goal is to open an image and by clicking a button or just pressing a key, it should move to the next image. 
Below is my code Ive tried, but it doesnt work and I couldnt come up with a better way to solve this...

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=700, height=700, cursor="cross")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\test2.jpg").resize((400,400))
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.create_image((0, 0), anchor="nw", image=self.photo)

    def update(self):
        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\test2.jpg").resize((400,400))
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.create_image((0, 0), anchor="nw", image=self.photo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
    app.update()
```

Would be great if someone could help me :D

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit too vague for a good question. What happens when the code runs? Do you get an error, and if so, what's the error? Does it show the wrong image? Does the program crash?

Comment: `app.update()` after `app.mainloop()` is useless - it is executed when window is already closed.

Comment: I don't see any bitton in code. And you don't bind() mouse click to canvas too.

Comment: today in this question I show how to add text to image on canvas - and code shows how to replace image on canvas when you click image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548811/unable-to-write-text-on-mouseclick-area-on-image/55551178#55551178

Comment: @furas so basically what you did is to delete the current image that is displayed and then just created another image right?

Comment: yes I use `canvas.delete()` to remove image from canvas and I put new image in the same place. Without `canvas.delete()` I would have two images on canvas - new one above previous one - but I don't need it. `canvas.delete()` removes only from canvas, not from memory. If you have this image still assigned to variable then you can put it on canvas again - so you can load images once and display them again and again.

Comment: @furas Well I tried to change this for my purpose. Basically by clicking it should open a new image from a path I assigned before. I deleted the "draw" part from "draw_text" and Im only left with the canvas.delete() and then I made the following change: `imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\36.jpg")` and `cv_img_id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=imgtk, anchor="nw")`
And by running this I get a KeyError: http://prntscr.com/n8ewbx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code change image when you click canvas (not only image).

I added only `self.bind('<Button-1>', self.update)` and `event` in `def update()`

I use variables `IMG1`, `IMG2` only to easily replace you files with mine.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

IMG1 = "C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\test2.jpg"
IMG2 = "C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\test2.jpg"

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=700, height=700, cursor="cross")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.image = Image.open(IMG1).resize((400,400))
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.create_image((0, 0), anchor="nw", image=self.photo)

        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.update)

    def update(self, event):
        self.image = Image.open(IMG2).resize((400,400))
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.create_image((0, 0), anchor="nw", image=self.photo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

But this code only change first image to second image. It doesn't change second but to first.